# cellcolor leaves a blank space at the right of a multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow, colortbl, cellcolor

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{0.9}\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{6cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{6cm}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|m{12cm}|}{\cellcolor{cyan!40}\Large\textbf{The
        quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox
        jumps over the lazy dog}}\\\hline
        First & Value 1\\\hline
        Second & Value 2\\\hline
        Third & Value 3\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that I'm not able to get rid of the blank space to the right:

[image: Table with blank background space on the right]

Comment: not `\cellcolor`'s fault (that would be impossible:-) your multicolumn span is not as wide as the columns it is spanning, the colour just makes that clearer

Comment: `\multicolumn{2}{|m{\dimexpr 12cm+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth }|}` so it spans the inter-column material

Comment: @DavidCarlisle your code gives me ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...pr 12cm+2\tabcolsep +\arryrulewidth

Comment: Solved, it was just a typo. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your multicolumn span is not as wide as the columns it is spanning, the colour just makes that clearer

Use `\multicolumn{2}{|m{\dimexpr 12cm+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth }|}` so it spans the inter-column material